# How can I tell whether a pointer/address is dynamically allocated?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks, memory-address

I'm trying to mitigate memory leaks.
Obviously the best solution is to not leak memory in the first place.

But in my case, I need to look at existing pointers, and determine if any of them are dynamically allocated and need to be deleted.

Given a specific address/pointer, does C++ provide a way to determine whether the given address points to the heap?

***BONUS:***
Does C++ provide a way to determine whether a given heap address needs to be deleted with `delete[]` versus plain `delete`?

Comment: There is no stock C++ way to know this.  If you have a specific implementation that you target, you should be able to find information about how to tell the difference on that platform.

Comment: The answer to your bonus question is to switch to smart pointers, like `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: With raw pointers there is no way to tell.  That's why smart pointers were invented.  You can then treat all raw pointers as observation (not owning) pointers.

Comment: Thanks guys. The problem I'm running into with smart pointers, is that they are not the same size (in bytes) as a dumb pointer. Dumb pointers are 8 bytes, and smart pointers are 16 bytes. I have always thought smart pointers should not need extra non-static member data, so this perplexes me. It is causing bugs in my application, and I'm trying to avoid the overhead because it's performance-sensitive (long hash/encrypt operations).

Comment: I suppose you could put any `delete` or `delete[]` operations into a `try ... catch` block. Not sure that's a *good* solution, though.

Comment: @Giffyguy I believe a `unique_ptr` has the same size as a raw pointer, unless you give it a custom deleter. `shared_ptr` needs extra storage to count how many `shared_ptr` exist to the same instance..

Comment: Short answer: no, to both questions asked. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: @AdrianMole It isn't a solution at all. Using `delete` or `delete[]` inappropriately is UB and probably won't throw an exception you can catch.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I was just going to add that UB to my comment. You saved me the effort. :-)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Interesting re: `uinque_ptr`. I'll look into that. Thanks.

Comment: @Giffyguy Depending on the implementation of `unique_ptr`, [it can have the same size as a pointer](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7cf34a4d385d29e3)

Comment: @Giffyguy You should not be passing smart pointers around your code (not very much that is). Use smart pointers to look after your dynamic object but pass around the raw pointer (or a reference) to the object itself. That way you know to NEVER delete a pointer because they will ALL be deleted by the smart pointer that is looking after the objects they point to.

Comment: A few people have hinted at it, but I wanted to explicitly say this feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're asking how to tell if a pointer is dynamically allocated so that you know if you should free it later, I think the question should be "how do I structure my program to minimize the chance of memory leaks?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ (and C) a pointer points to any address. To know what type of memory you are pointing to, you need to look at the process memory map. This will be platform specific.

On Linux the `/proc/<pid>/maps` file contains this info.

However, even if the pointer points to the heap, it still might not be deletable if it is an increment (think arrays) of a newed pointer, or if it was allocated using `malloc` instead of `new`.

Comment: Another common example is if `new` a class type object, pointers to any of it's data members will point to free store but those objects can't be directly `delete`d. You can also have pointers to storage allocated with `malloc` which you can't `delete` and may appear in the same region of memory as `new`ed objects.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ohhh, the `malloc` thing is actually a major issue. Definitely need to watch out for that. Good thinking.

Answer (score 2):

You should use smart pointers.

You can not know where a pointer points to but using smart pointers means you can avoid having to delete *any* pointers.

Create your smart pointer at a place in your code that will live as long as you need to use the object it points to. Then, do not pass the smart pointer around your code (unless you need to transfer/share ownership), just pass a *reference* to the object it points to (or the raw pointer).

When ALL your objects are managed by smart pointers in this way you **never** have to *delete* any of the pointers in your code, because you know that there is a smart pointer that will take care of the deletion at the correct time.

```
void func(Object const& o) { /* ... */ }
void other_func(Object const* pp) { /* ... */ }

// ... somewhere else in the codebase

auto object_ptr = std::make_unique<Object>();

func(*object_ptr); // call function with a reference

other_func(object_ptr.get()); // call function with a raw pointer
```

**BONUS:**

No.

It is on you to know what you created, but, again, the smart pointer will take care of that for you:

```
auto array_ptr = std::make_unique<Object[]>(25); // allocate an array
```

Comment: If you cannot know, can you explain why the accepted answer that describes exactly how to know is wrong, please?

Comment: @xaxxon It is wrong because a pointer may point to a sub-object within a larger allocated object or general memory area. It is therefore *impossible* to know if you can legally deallocate the raw pointer or not, regardless of whether or not its address range falls within that of "heap allocated memory".

Comment: @xaxxon And even if you could determine if the raw pointer is pointing to a whole allocated object within the dynamic allocation address range, you have no idea whether or not it is already being managed by its own smart pointer elsewhere or if some other component is already tasked with its destruction. There is simply no way to know, from the pointer alone, if it is safe to *delete* it.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I tell whether a pointer/address is dynamically allocated?

## You cannot in general.

The [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of your process is likely to change. So `::operator new` (or [malloc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html)) is often implemented to use system calls (on Linux, [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) or [sbrk(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html)) or to reuse previously `free`-d memory (or `::operator delete`-d one).

On Linux, you could parse `/proc/self/maps` - see [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

Study also the implementation of [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/), and be aware of the [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) instrumentation [options of GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html).

In C++, you could use [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory), and the [garbage collection handbook](https://gchandbook.org/) explains many related issues (a major one being [circular references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference), which with multi-threading becomes a complex issue).

C++ also has [placement `new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new).

On Linux, you can [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) many plugins, and that also adds complexity, but is quite useful (see [Qt](https://qt.io/) or [RefPerSys](https://refpersys.org/) as examples, and read the [C++ dlopen minihowto](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/C++-dlopen/)).